# run a shell script from Python GUI

Tags: python

I've a GUI which will perform some functions when the buttons are pressed.

now i want to create a button in the GUI which will call and run a shell script in the background.

how can i achieve this ?

Comment: try https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if your question is about how to call a shell script in Python, or how to make a button in your GUI. If the former, my comment above (recommending some research on [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)) is the solution. Otherwise:

```
# assuming Python3
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub

WINDOW_SIZE = "600x400"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)

tk.Button(root, text="Push me!", command=lambda: sub.call('path/to/script')).pack()
```

Comment: i know how to create a button i just want to know how to call the shell program, sorry for the ambiguity in the question

Comment: @AdamSmith It shows an error saying OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: @kingmakerking Then you don't have permission to run that script from where you are. You'll have to get your OS to let you run it -- that's not a Python thing

Comment: @AdamSmith No I do have permissions. Still not working?

Comment: @kingmakerking That error means the OS is not allowing you to launch that script because you do not have permission to do so. Good luck!

Comment: @AdamSmith I set the permission to 777 and executed as python pythoncode.py and it didnt do anything. Didnt open any window, neither any message.

Comment: @kingmakerking sorry this seems like a completely different issue than the one my answer addresses. Maybe consider writing your own question with the code in question?

Answer (score 1):

Python can run shell scripts using the supbprocess module. In order to run it in the background you can start it from a new thread.

To use the module

```
import subprocess
...
subprocess.call(['./yourScript.sh'])
```

For a good python threading resource you can try: [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @lakesh said, below is the complete script :

```
import Tkinter
import subprocess

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
   print "Below is the output from the shell script in terminal"
   subprocess.call('./yourscript.sh', shell=True)


B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Please note that the shell script is in the same directory as that of the python script.

If needed, do `chmod 777 yourscript.sh`

```
subprocess.call('./yourscript.sh', shell=True)
```

and `import Tkinter` and **not** `import tkinter` solved the problems I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tkinter to create a button. For more info, look at this video:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr60hWFyKHc

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app,"Shell Script")
button1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

To add the functionality:
change button1 line to:

```
button1 = Button(app,"Shell Script",command=runShellScript)

def runShellScript():
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(['./yourScript.sh'])
```

Comment: It throws an error " NameError: name 'runShellScript' is not defined